# Disable access to files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have folder `/texts/`

There are a lot of `*.txt` files inside.

How do I enable access to these files by php scripts on my site, but disable direct access by the browser?

Thanks.

Comment: You already tagged your question `.htaccess`. In absence of other requirements `Deny from all` would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the folder to somewhere outside the document root of the web server.

Alternatively, add [`Deny from all`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#Deny) to the configuration for that directory.

Comment: This is the most secure way. Relying on .htaccess means you are relying on server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file if you can't move *.txt files out of your DocumentRoot:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*\.txt$ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the texts/ dir create an .htaccess file with this content:

```
#htaccess
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the folder in you web directory if you don't have to. If only php needs those files, it can read them from anywhere on your disk.